# How to connect iOS app with non iOS Bluetooth devices?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I want to connect my iOS application with a bluetooth device which is non iOS based device and used for measuring Glucohealth and  also not MFI compliant. Is there any way to connect iOS app with that device? If yes, then how? I searched that before 2 years it was not possible. But need to know if this can be possible now?

Comment: Is this a development question or a how do I use an app question? if the later, check out http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @user2955864: Have you got solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

Now you can do it with help of [CoreBluetooth](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html) framework if you device is Bluetooth 4.0-compliant.

If it supports only Bluetooth Classic then you can't communicate with it if it is MFi-compliant device